# How to access modules from mura tag in content

Tags: mura

I'd like to access the modules directory in `/themes/[themename]/modules instead of /sites/default/themes/[themename]/modules/` from `[mura]-tag` in content

This is Mura Core Version 7.1.438

> [mura]dspInclude('themes/[themename]/modules/sprachweiche.cfm')[/mura]

```
Error 500
Could not find the included template /muraWRM/sites/default/themes/[themename]/modules/sprachweiche.cfm.
```

Answer (score 1):

To display a registered module, simply use the following syntax, and pass in the directory name of your module.

`[m]$.dspObject(object='your-module-directory-name-goes-here')[/m]`

That said, in your example though, it doesn't appear to be a valid "module", since you're attempting to include a file called `sprachweiche.cfm`. So, if you simply want to include a file, I wouldn't put it under the `modules` directory. So, if you have a directory under your theme called `includes`, you could use this instead:

`[m]$.dspThemeInclude('includes/sprachweiche.cfm')[/m]`

This method automatically generates the path to your theme, so you can simply pass in the rest of the path to your desired file.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve

[m]$.dspThemeInclude('includes/sprachweiche.cfm')[/m] caused the error:
Could not find the included template /muraWRM/themes/[themename]/includes/sprachweiche.cfm.

But including the modules directory to the path works:
[m]$.dspThemeInclude('modules/includes/sprachweiche.cfm')[/m]